# What is the relation between consciousness and thinking?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, consciousness

This jumble of questions isn't organized in any specific way. Please don't feel the need to address all the questions.

Do we need the ability to think or be in possession of a unifying self to be conscious? What is the word for being conscious of one's own conscious states?

Comment: no research effort whatsoever

Comment: @Banana  How would you evaluate the neuroscience answers to your questions?

Comment: Consciousness is perception. You need to perceive (be aware of your existence is perception) to think.

Comment: The word you're after may be 'apperception'.

Answer (score 0):

1 You have to be conscious to be aware that you can think.
2 The ability to think is necessary but not sufficient to be conscious.
3 Having a unifying self is consciousness.
4 Being conscious of our conscious states is called meditation.